# Check width of viewport on side load, then add class to body if less than X

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, coffeescript

I'm currently building a portfolio site and i want the sidebar to be hidden by default on mobile devices since its quite big atm, you can check it out here: www.dosh.dk/rofl/

The sidebar will hide if body has the class "sidebar-inactive" and therefore i want to do a single check on the viewport when the site is loaded and then add the class if below X

Im using coffeescript and ive made the following code but it doesnt seem to work, any ideas?

```
$ ->
  $(".inner_content").hide()
  $("#myskills").show()
  $("#site").addClass 'loaded'

  if $(window).width < 600
     $("body").addClass 'sidebar-inactive'
```

Comment: .width() -> is a function, dont miss the **()**

Comment: Don't check viewport width using window width, use `window.matchMedia` instead, handling cross browser scrollbars: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia  See polyfill to support IE10<: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, totally forgot the ()

Answer (score 0):

How about a non-JavaScript solution using CSS media queries?

```
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

This will hide elements with the `sidebar` class when the screen is less than 600px wide and will update as the browser is resized.

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries